# int* array to short* array conversion

Tags: c

This question might be silly for you guys, but I am new in C. I need to convert my int* array to short* array. Here is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define file_path "/app/diag/Sound/test_gen.wav"
int main() 
{
  long data_size;
  data_size = get_file_size(file_path);

  int *data = (int *) malloc(data_size * sizeof(int));
  readPCM(data, 44100, 16, data_size);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Now I need to convert the data array to short* array. How can I do that? Example code would be really appreciable. I know how to do it in Java. Check out my code below.

I do know how to work it in Java. Check out my code for Java:

```
public static short[] encodeToSample(byte[] srcBuffer, int numBytes) {
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[2];
    int nSamples = numBytes / 2;        
    short[] samples = new short[nSamples];  // 16-bit signed value
    for (int i = 0; i < nSamples; i++) {
        tempBuffer[0] = srcBuffer[2 * i];
        tempBuffer[1] = srcBuffer[2 * i + 1];
        samples[i] = bytesToShort(tempBuffer);
    }
    return samples;
}
public static short bytesToShort(byte [] buffer) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    bb.put(buffer[0]);
    bb.put(buffer[1]);
    return bb.getShort(0);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: change your `int` keywords to `short`. What else?

Comment: Well, I think thats not gonna work. because PCM data is not gonna be converted just by casting.

Comment: oh, i see... ok

Comment: Create a new array and copy the elements in a loop.

Comment: for those who don't know Java, it might help if you give some examples of the expected output for a given input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define file_path "/app/diag/Sound/test_gen.wav"
int main() 
{
  long data_size;
  data_size = get_file_size(file_path);

  int *data = (int *) malloc(data_size * sizeof(int));
  short *data2 = (short*) malloc(2 * data_size * sizeof(short)); //notice the doubled size
  readPCM(data, 44100, 16, data_size);
  for(int i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
  {
     data2[2 * i] = data[i] >> 16; // get the 16 most significant
     data2[2 * i + 1] = data[i] & 0xFFFF; //get the 16 least significant
  }
  free(data);
}
```

Comment: I see what you are suggesting. It is basically doing the same thing what you have commented above. But I have updated my question. Check it out. I know how to do it in Java. But I dont know how to do it in C. Reason is int byte array to short conversion will always be half of its original length.

Comment: @SubbirRahman you want to split each int into 2 shorts?

Comment: Keep in mind that the C standard doesn't specify that `int` is twice as big as `short`.  Both are required to be at least 16 bits in width and the former must be at least as wide as the latter.  Granted, on a lot of systems, the widths will be 32 and 16 bits, respectively.  If complete portability is not a huge concern, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Well, if they had equal sizes then he probably wouldn't need the conversion, right?

Comment: Yahh.. No worries about that.. I have done the other part actually. So basically the length of the data is half of the original data

Comment: Low16short = data[i] & 0xFFFF